# How to change theme attributes dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-theme

In my app, I have multiple user accounts. Each user can define their own set of colors. Such as `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, `colorAccent` etc. So whenever a user get logged in, the activity will use the user defined `colors` for `theme`.

For better understanding, say my `user` is:

```java
class User {
    String user_name = "Iron Man";
    int colorPrimary = Color.RED;
    int colorAccent = Color.BLUE;
    ...
```

**Note: User can choose any color. So there will be no predefined themes.**

Is it possible to apply theme attributes totally dynamically and only from the code?

Answer (score 2):

I have created the same idea in my two apps, you have two options

The first option, create many themes in your theme.xml file and change the full theme depend on the user using the setTheme function from activity, for example, dark theme, white theme, blue theme...etc like Askfm App

Check this app code, I have created this feature on it
https://github.com/amrdeveloper/askme

The second option, give the user the ability to change everything using a color picker
and use some functions like getSupportActionBar, setStatusBarColor, setNavigationBarColor, and SharedPreferences to change theme

I have implemented this idea on my app you can check the result from the link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amrdeveloper.materialtimer

but you can't edit theme XML from the runtime because it immutable

Comment: I think you can create 3 attribute class that every theme contains and create an event listener but you will also change the color of your 50 views manual, or search all views that have old color and set the new color for it, We can search if we can generate XML theme in an external file, not themes.xml, and using setTheme to apply this theme

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm trying to use predefined themes. But I am facing this problem... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352455/how-to-retrive-and-use-a-style-attribute-from-code)