# How to retrive and use a style attribute from code?

Tags: java, android, styles, android-theme

I have defined a theme in `style.xml` file.

```xml
    <style name="ThemePurple" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPurple</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPurpleDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPurpleAccent</item>
    </style>
```

I want to use the `colorPrimary` of this theme to a `textView` in a `recyclerView`. I've tried this:

```java
int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.colorPrimary};
TypedArray typedArray = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.ThemePurple, attrs);
holder.titleView.setTextColor(typedArray.getColor(0, Color.BLACK));
typedArray.recycle();
```

But this is not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not `android.R.attr.colorPrimary`, but just `R.attr.colorPrimary`

`android` prefix means you want to get built-in value, e.g. `android:colorPrimary`

you are using compat lib (AndroidX probably) which delivers newer attributes to older system versions, so these parameteres are in fact "custom", without `android:` prefix

Answer (score 2):

For **Kotlin**:

```
val typedValue = TypedValue()
context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true)
holder.titleView.setTextColor(typedValue.data)
```

For **Java:**

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
holder.titleView.setTextColor(typedValue.data);
```